# Why is EF Core not updating a column in the database when entity is attached and ChangeTracker shows the change

Tags: entity-framework-core, savechanges

I updated three properties of an entity. The ChangeTracker.DebugView corectly shows the entity as Modified as well as the three properties that I changed as modified.

When I call DbContext.SaveChanges() two of the modified properties get correctly updated to the database, but one property `Notes` does not get updated.

Note: The property on the class does NOT have the attribute `[NotMapped]`.

I ran the SQL Profiler to inspect the calls to the database and the `UPDATE` statement shows all modified columns except `Notes`, which explains why it did not get updated to the database.

Why is the property getting omitted from the `UPDATE` statement, when the ChangeTracker correctly sees the property/column as modified?

See below from ChangeTracker.DebugView:

```
MyEntity {ID: 1} Modified
  ID: 1 PK
  SampleGuid: '72A2DFAA-0EB9-4408-AF68-BBE0294C3179' Modified Originally <null>
  ParentID: 1 FK
  Notes: 'Here are some notes...' Originally <null>
  LastUpdatedTime: <null>
  Status: 2 Modified Originally 1
```

SQL Profiler - `Notes` missing from `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[MyEntity] SET [SampleGuid] = @p0, [Status] = @p1
OUTPUT 1
WHERE [ID] = @p2;
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Working on it... Studying/migrating a large project written by someone else from EF 6 to EF Core.